# BACKSPACE tab is not working after reaching MAX length of the String in Entry widget in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I created a Tkinter Entry Box widget which takes only integers of length 6.I gave an input value of '1465146'. it reached it's maximum limit but when i want to delete/Edit  the inserted text using "backspace key" it is not working. I am unable to Delete or Edit the text.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        vcmd = (self.register(self.onValidate),
            '%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, height=10, width=40)
        self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.text.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    def onValidate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
        valid=self.Check_num(s,S)   
        return valid

    def Check_num(self,s,S):
        if S in '\b1234567890' and len(s)<=6:   
            return True
        else:return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what have you done to debug this problem? Have you examined what `s` and `S` are when you press the backspace key? Do you know what `s` and `S` are supposed to contain when you click the backspace key?

Comment: yes. I debugged  i have given  input '1465146'  when i press backspace the 'S' has value'6' and 's' has value '1465146'.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a value such as "1234567" and then press the backspace key, you are doing two checks: are the characters being inserted or deleted in one of the allowed characters, and is the length *of the text before the edit* less than seven. In this case, the length is exactly 7 before you hit the backspace, so the edit is disallowed.

If you want to make sure that the widget only lets you enter 6 digits, you should be comparing the length of the `%P` parameter, which is the final string if the edit is allowed.

Also, having `\b` in the list of allowed characters isn't going to do what you think it does. It's going to let you insert a literal `\b` (control-h, ascii character 8) into the string. If you want only digits, you should check against only digits. When you press the backspace key, `s` will *not* be `\b`.

Finally, checking that `s` is in `1234567890` is not going to do exactly what you think it's going to do. You're assuming that `s` is a single character but it can be multiple characters if the user pastes something into the input field. For example, it will prevent you from copying and pasting the string "21" into the input field since the two-byte sequence "21" is not in the string "1234567890".

Comment: thanks @Bryan .%P parameter helped me to resolve the issue.